# Optional peer dependency only for TypeScript typings?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, redux, react-redux

I have a TypeScript library that implements a React component. One of the optional features is you can pass an instance of a Redux store as a prop to the component for Redux integration.

```
<Component reduxStore={store}></Component>
```

This is an optional prop, and the library only ever imports the `Store` type from the Redux package to enforce types. Consumers of my library who don't use Redux won't ever need this dependency, and it shouldn't be bundled in their final build.

Currently I include the Redux package as a `dependency` which is causing some issues. In Redux, the typings are included in the package, but the `Store` type has been changing in more recent versions of the Redux library. This means people using my library and TypeScript who have their own version of Redux installed as a dependency can run into type mismatches between the type information installed in my library, and the same type installed in their library.

This seems like a good case for listing the dependency as a peer dependency, except it's an optional feature and consumers of the library shouldn't be required to install Redux if they don't intend to use the integration feature.

Is there a better way to handle type information for libraries so small changes in types between dependency versions won't throw type mismatch errors for consumers of my library?

Two possible solutions I can think of might be:

1. Set the `reduxStore` optional prop to type `any`, and before using the `dispatch` method that is expected to be on the `Store`, do a null reference check. This could work, but diminishes the ability to catch errors at build time.
2. Maybe there is a way to create my own custom `Store` interface that only enforces the small subset of methods I plan to use.
3. Create a separate package for those who want to integrate with Redux that wraps the core component... This could be a huge headache architecturally.

Comment: [`optionalDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) look promising

Comment: Npm generally calls these kind of dependencies "peer dependencies", the only problem with this is how typescript sees them if they are absent

Comment: @Ferrybig, that's exactly right. Because if the consumer doesn't have the package it throws errors. But also, if a consumer doesn't even use TypeScript why should they have to install the Redux library which they never plan to use, just to get typings they'll never need?

Comment: My tl;dr; is I don't think you should do it this way. Difficult typing can be a consequence of underlying issues of overly controlling entities that are doing too much. If the consumers of your library want to use redux, it should be their responsibility to implement it and create wrappers around your library's components to implement it. You pigeonhole them into using redux as well. What if they want to use the context api? You can add a small tutorial in your README on how to incorporate redux if they want to use it

Comment: I see your point. In my situation, the library is already a wrapper around a complex library and I basically create a series of wrappers to integrate the `complex library` with Redux, Context API, and other patterns to make it easier to integrate. Sounds like you're suggesting something closer to `Solution 3` that I mention in the question. I think there's a lot of truth to the overly controlling entities statement you've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to provide an optional HOC that accepts a generic. Your users can wrap your components with it. Your concerns are differing type versions and bound dependencies. This means you have no choice but to let the user decide what types they use.

```js
const useStore:<Store = any> = (store: Store) => WrappedComponent => {
   return (props) => <WrappedComponent {...props} store={store} />
}
```

and its implementation in a component would look like this:

```js
import {Store} from 'react-redux';
useStore<Store>(store)(Component)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think removing the typings for the Redux implementation is what I will do for now. Having a specific HOC for this scenario is a solid idea, and it decouples the redux logic from the core functionality of my component. `useStore` would conflict with React hook naming convention, so something like `withStore` would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewCraswell Yea, that was my thought process. If you have separate HOCs for each flux implementation you want to use, it'll be easier to manage types. You don't have to check for `undefined` values (a colossal pain) if you make the user have the conscious choice of incorporating redux.